# Ruby search on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app i need to search via some field in table, but main trouble is that i must do it so:
If i have choosen select field in view A, i must search only by A condition, if both A and B then by A and B...
Now i have:

controller

```
@pre_oils = Oil.by_brand(params[:oilbrand]).by_oiloiliness(params[:oiloiliness]).by_structure(params[:oilstructure]).by_size(params[:oilsize])
```

model

```
def self.by_oiloiliness(oiloiliness)
    if oiloiliness
      where("description LIKE ?", "%#{oiloiliness}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end

  def self.by_brand(brand)
    if brand
      where("manufacturer LIKE ?", "%#{brand}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end

  def self.by_structure(structure)
    if structure
      #where("structure LIKE ?", "%#{structure}%")
      where("description LIKE ?", "%#{structure}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end

  def self.by_size(size)
    if size
      where("capacity LIKE ?", "#{size}")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

But it is searching very very strange, one time is working, another no.... What is bad? And how to search only by such fields, wich are choosen in view?

(also ruby 1.9.3 rails 3.2.8)

maybe something with fetching with find on all queries and then split them and delete duplicates?

**upd**

```
 oil = Oil.brand_like(params[:oilbrand])
    oil = Oil.description_like(params[:oiloiliness])
    oil = Oil.description_like(params[:oilstructure])
    oil = Oil.capacity_eq(params[:oilsize])
```

**upd2**

@pre_oils = Oil.search(:manufacturer_like => params[:oilbrand], :description_like => params[:oiloiliness], :description_like => params[:oilstructure], :capacity_eq => params[:oilsize])

Comment: `where("capacity LIKE ?", "#{size}")` - there's no `%`. Why?

Comment: @jdoe this is not the problem.... it must be so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of things there are many gems available. You can go through gems like [meta_search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search), [searchlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) to perform your search.

Once you install `meta_search` you can do like this:

When you have `form` with fields like following:

```
 <%= f.text_filed :capacity_eq %>
 <%= f.text_field :description_like %>
```

You will get params like this:

```
 params => {"description_like" => "xyz", "capacity_eq" => "21"}

 Oil.search(params)  #To get your results
```

Comment: and how append all searches in one var? also how to use there %like%

Comment: You need to `name` your view fields like: for doing `like` operation filed name should be `description_like`, for exact match field name should be `capacity_eq` and so on. You go through gem doc. You will get to know things.

Comment: hm didn't see there how to combain three queries results in one last result variable

Comment: It will give combined result. If params present it will search with that condition otherwise not.

Comment: see upd: how to get, that variable oil contain all 4 query?

Comment: You can combine like this: `oil =[]; oil += Oil.brand_like(params[:oilbrand]);
      oil+=Oil.description_like(params[:oiloiliness]);
    oil += Oil.description_like(params[:oilstructure]);` But this is ugly way to do. Go down to doc you can see `search` method. Use that as I mention in `answer`.

Comment: if you paste your `view` code with search field. I will guide you.

Comment: paste complete `params`. First try it in rails console by creating `params` hash. get working there then put in view and controller.

Comment: by upd2 (see it) i get undefined method `search' but i have added gem 'searchlogic' to gemfile and bundled

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24923/discussion-between-brabertaser1992-and-codeit)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021826/metasearch-rails-gem-multiple-time-search-by-field

Comment: why you are ignoring me( ?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 are u there?

Answer (score 0):

Use ActiveRecord

define db abstract class

```
require 'active_record'
class MyDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection(
    #...
    :username => "",
    :password => "",
    :url => "")
end
```

define your table model

```
require './my_database'
class Oil < MyDatabase
  self.table_name = 'oils'
end
```

Then use it

```
Oil.where('brand LIKE ? and oiloilness LIKE ?', params[:oilbrand], params[:oiloilness])
```

Comment: undefined method `find_all_by_brand_and_oiloiliness_and_structure_and_size'

Comment: He was suggesting you should write a method find_all_by_brand_and_oiloiliness_and_structure_and_size

Comment: If this was a Rails app you can call that method directly.  It does not appear to be a Rails app.