# Metasearch rails gem multiple time search by field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

I have such code of searching (with metasearch rails gem):

```
@pre_oils = Oil.search({:manufacturer_like => params[:oilbrand], :description_like => params[:oiloiliness], :description_like => params[:oilstructure], :capacity_eq => params[:oilsize]})
```

But i must to search via description with like on two params: oiloiliness, oilstructure... In some cases i could have first, but didn'r have oilstructure or have oilstructure but didn't have oiloiliness...

if i leave

```
@pre_oils = Oil.search({:manufacturer_like => params[:oilbrand], :description_like => params[:oiloiliness], :capacity_eq => params[:oilsize]})
```

all is ok

Now it is not searching via oiloiliness, but why ? How to do it? How to search via both fields?